# Facebook : How to show the Facebook page likes count and Like button to like the Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I have created a page "Education For All" in facebook. In my website i want to provide a like button to  like this **page** not the **url** and also want to show the count of the Likes received for that page in website along with Like button. I have used "Add this", but it is showing the count of number of likes for the url. Can you suggest me any plugin ?

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

generate your facebook like button from here,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Please provide proper informations to get the proper code, or you can use the code below by following the instructions, just replace **http://www.yoururl.com** with the desired URL of the page which needs to be liked:-

**1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yoururl.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: i want to like an facebook page, so i hav to give the url of that facebook page?

Comment: which image you want to change?

Comment: Take a look at this link it may help you, but it doesn't work on IE http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/

Comment: These thinks are now blocked by browsers like Firefox due to tracking protection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to generate the like button through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ?

It gives you this code for example:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fedforall&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=225116190942635" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```